# Regex to extract number between parenthesis at the end of string

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get the number that is between parenthesis from the **end** of string?

- `filename(1)`  - I will get `1`
- `filename(12)`  - I will get `12`
- `filename(0)` - I will get `0`
- `file(4)name`  - I will get nothing
- `(4)filename`  - I will get nothing
- `filename4`  - I will get nothing

Comment: What did you try? What were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
\((\d+)\)$
```

test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/zL634t/1)